# How to access the remote .mdb file in shared folder using java and jackcess from linux machine

Tags: java, linux

This is my first post. I am trying to open the remote .mdb file which is in shared folder in Windows machine from the linux machine using jackcess lib. and set the table values in busineess object. I wrote the below code.

Scenario 1 : I have run the code from windows machine it is working fine. Scenario 2 : If i run the code from linux machine it is getting file not found exception. Hope it should be small mistake. Please correct me what am missing here .

```
package com.gg.main;   

import java.io.File;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.util.ArrayList;   
import java.util.Map;   
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database;   
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Table;   
import com.penske.model.Login;   


public class Test {   

public static void main(String args[]){       
    Table table = null;   
    Database db = null;   
    Login login = null;   
    ArrayList<Login> rowList = null;   
    try {   
    rowList = new ArrayList();   
    db = Database.open(new File("//aa.bb.com/file/access.mdb"));   

    table = db.getTable("Maintenance");   
    System.out.println(Database.open(new File("//aa.bb.com/file/access.mdb"))   
               .getTable("Maintenance").getColumns());   
    for(Map<String, Object> row : table) {   
        login = new Login();   
        if(row.get("Req_ID")!=null){   
        login.setId(row.get("Req_ID").toString());   
        }   
        if(row.get("Name")!=null){   
        login.setName(row.get("Name").toString());   
        }if(row.get("Loc")!=null){   
        login.setLoc(row.get("Loc").toString());   
        }   
        rowList.add(login);                
    }   

    login.setRowList(rowList);   
    } catch (IOException e1) {   
    e1.printStackTrace();   
    }   
}   

}
```

Comment: I've never used jackcess, but one idea is to open a shell window on the Linux machine and type "ls -l //aa.bb.com/file/access.mdb". Does it say "No such file or directory"? In that case, your path name is wrong. Also, perhaps you shouldn't open the file a second time, in the println?

Answer (score 0):

Linux does not have native support for Windows' UNC path, as you use them here:

```
new File("//aa.bb.com/file/access.mdb")
```

You'll have to mount the remote filesystem somewhere in your Linux filesystem where your program can access it and then replace the paths in your program to use that local filesystem path, using smbfs or something like it. It's been a long time since I've had to interact with Windows machines, but it should go something like this:

```
mount -t smbfs -o username=foo,password=bar //aa.bb.com/file /mnt/whatever_you_choose_to_name_it
```

See [the manpage for smbmount](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/smbmount8.html) for details.

Of course, if your program is supposed to start automatically eg. as part of the system booting, you'll have to see to it that the filesystem is automatically mounted as well. See `fstab(5)`.